# TSQL combine multiple records

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that contains:

```
Code     ID1        ID2 
Blue     1           2 
Blue                 3 
Blue                 4 
Green    1           5 
Green                10 
Green                12
```

I need the result set:

```
Code      ID1       ID2 
Blue      1         2
Blue      1         3
Blue      1         4 
Blue      1         5 
Green     1         5
Green     1         10 
Green     1         12
```

The number in ID1 does not always start with a  1.

Any ideas??  I am stumped!

Comment: a) Where is `Blue,1,5` coming from? b) have you considered `ISNULL(ID1,1) AS ID1` ?

Comment: What should `ID1` contain? Barring any further details about this, it might help to assign that column a default value so that it's never `NULL`.

Comment: ID1 could be any value..   In my example, I just used 1 - but it could be anything (500, 528, 2574....)

Comment: I went ahead and wrote a cursor to loop through all the records.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drop Table T1
Create table T1( Code varchar(10), Id1 int, Id2 int )
Insert T1 Values
('Blue',   11,  2),
('Blue',   12,  3), 
('Blue', NULL,  4),
('Blue',   15,  5),
('Blue', NULL,  6),
('Green',  23, 21),
('Green',  24, 24),
('Green',NULL, 25),
('Green',NULL, 28),
('Green',  27, 29),
('Red',    35, 33),
('Red',  NULL, 36),
('Red',  NULL, 38)

SELECT 
    A.Code, ISNULL(A. Id1,B.LastId) Id1 , A.Id2 
FROM T1 A
CROSS APPLY( 
            Select Top 1 Id1 as LastId  
            From T1 
            where A.Code = T1.Code and Id2 <= A.Id2
            order by id1 desc   
            ) B
```